# Identifying old cabinet latch

Tags: cabinets, hardware, antique

I bought an old piece of furniture with two cabinet doors. One of them is missing a catch, and I am having a hard time identifying it. The overall dimensions of the latch are about 1" x 0.5".  I have included a picture of the catch on the other door.

I am hoping to find out what kind of catch this is, and how I can obtain a replacement for the missing one. If these aren't available anymore then a close approximation would also be helpful.
[image]

[image]

Here is a picture of what hooks onto the catch. It's basically just a screw.

[image]

Comment: Would say it is more of a cabinet catch.  Might help if we had a picture of where it goes in, the second part of the catch.

Comment: None of that hardware looks original, or historic.  Why go to trouble to find parts for it?  Why not just completely replace all the hardware?  You can get antique hardware from collectors stores, replicas on line, or pretty new stuff that would complement your new purchase.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a vintage *roller catch*, similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a “friction” catch that has a portion of it broken off.

I’d try Emtek website. Try googling Emtek cabinet catch hardware. Terrible website, but great customer service. Give them a call if you don’t find it on their website.

https://www.build.com/search?term=cabinet+catch